# Adaptive step size for Euler Method - How to create?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, nonlinear-dynamics, eulers-method

I think Euler's Method is a great way to simulate ODE:s. It's not the most accurate, but it's the fastest and simplest.

Euler's Method is usually used with fixed step size, where $k$ is the step size larger than $0$ and $\dot x = f(x,u)$ is our ODE function.

To simulate forward Euler, just iterate this equation:

$$x_{i+1} = x_i + k f(x_i, u)$$

To improve stability for Euler's method, then the step size $k$ needs to be adaptive. The smaller choice of the step $k$, the more stability is guaranteed, but the less accurate the simulation will become. Instead, the adaptive method for the step size is often used to find the best $k$.

**Question:**

I can I improve stability for Euler's method by implementing adaptive step size?

Comment: Your equation for Euler’s method is not correct.

Comment: I think you should consider the runge-kutta 4th order method.  It is very accurate and efficient, and in my opinion, much better than Euler's primitive method.

Comment: It is $x_{i+1}=x_i+hf(x_i,u(t_i))$. You could select $h$ so that the product $hf$ is constant with a small value. Or use step-doubling for the error estimate, this can look like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49256309/matlab-euler-explicit-ode-solver-with-adaptable-step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a second order method to compute the error estimate. You can use any of
\begin{array}{c|cc}
0&\\
c&c\\
\hline
&1-\frac1{2c}&\frac1{2c}
\end{array}
The Heun method, $c=1$, has the advantage that one can re-use the second slope as the first slope in the next step.

```
h=h0
k1 = f(t,y)    # derivative to be used for the explicit Euler step
while t<tf:
    k2 = f(t+h,y+h*k1)
    err = 0.5*abs(k1-k2)
    fac = tol/err  # better use relative error
    if fac > 1: # accept step
        y += h*k1; k1 = k2  # Euler step, derivative was already computed
        t += h
        # collect t,y in some output structure or print to file
    h = 0.9*fac*h
    # for exploration collect t,h in output structure or a second file
# return output structure
```

In the comments the question for a variable-step Heun method came up. I cited the third-order methods in [Butcher: *"Low-order methods"*, slide 26,](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/%7Ebutcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/low-order-RK.pdf) as any explicit 3rd order method contains second order method in its first two stages. In [Feldman: *"Variable step size methods"*](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Efeldman/math/vble.pdf) you can find several tested low-order embedded methods. For instance one based on Heun's method attributed to Fehlberg that probably started him to search for higher order embedded methods
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
0&\\
1&1\\
\frac12&\frac14&\frac14\\
\hline
&\frac16&\frac16&\frac46
\end{array}
This computes from the Heun data of the first two stages the point and derivative at the midpoint of the interval. Then applying the Simpson rule to these approximations results in an order 3 approximation.

```
h=h0
while t<tf:
    k1 = f(t,y)
    k2 = f(t+h,y+h*k1)
    k12 = 0.5*(k1+k2)   # combined slope for Heun step
    k3 = f(t+0.5*h,y+0.5*k12)
    err = (2/3)*abs(k12-k3)
    fac = tol/err  # better use relative error
    if fac > 1: # accept step
        y += h*k12  # Heun step, this is a new point
        t += h
        # collect t,y in some output structure or print to file
    h = 0.9*fac*h
    # for exploration collect t,h in output structure or a second file
# return output structure
```

Comment: Great! So the Heun method has adaptive step size?

Comment: Yes and no, as it is it only provides adaptive step size to the Euler method. One could modify this to an extrapolation method using the Heun step. In [Butcher: Low order methods](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/low-order-RK.pdf) on slide 26 first row right you find a third order method that can compute the Heun method from the first 2 stages, so that one could implement a more classical embedded method (classical = like RKF45, extrapolation = like Dormand-Prince 45).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Here is some code you might like. https://github.com/rwinklerwilkes/Matlab/blob/master/chapter5.m

Comment: Which if them do you find most useful?

Comment: Heun3 and RK4 have nice structures with "small" numbers. RKF45 is a nice robust workhorse if one can "hide" the step update computation. The error estimate here is really an estimate, so the step size control can have a simple implementation. Unlike the extrapolation methods where the error estimate is more an error guidance as it is somewhat "out of phase" from the actual error. // Your Heun3 implementation evaluates `f(a,w(i))` twice.